Discrete Blue and Red Game
This question was inspired by this question.
The game is played on the set $\{1, 2, 3,...,n\}$. Blue and Red take alternating turns, starting with Blue, where each player chooses a number from the set which hasn't already been chosen by either player in an earlier turn, and colours it in their colour. After each player makes $m$ turns, the game is finished.
If $1\le r_1<r_2<...<r_m\le n$ are the red numbers at the end of the game, we say that each set $\{r_{i-1}+1, r_{i-1}+2, ..., r_{i}-1\}$ is blue if and only if it contains at least one blue number. (Here we take $r_0 = 0$, $r_{m+1}=n+1$)
Similarly, if $1\le b_1<b_2<...<b_m\le n$ are the blue numbers at the end of the game, we say that each set $\{b_{i-1}+1, b_{i-1}+2, ..., b_{i}-1\}$ is red if and only if it contains at least one red number. (Here we take $b_0 = 0$, $b_{m+1}=n+1$)
Blue's score is the sum of cardinalities of blue sets, and Red's score is the sum of cardinalities of red sets. The player with the bigger score wins.

Here is an illustration game with $n=11,$ $m = 3$:
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{lightgray}{2}\space\color{lightgray}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{lightgray}{5}\space\color{lightgray}{6}\space\color{lightgray}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{lightgray}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{lightgray}{5}\space\color{lightgray}{6}\space\color{lightgray}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{lightgray}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{lightgray}{5}\space\color{red}{6}\space\color{lightgray}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{lightgray}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{lightgray}{5}\space\color{red}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{red}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{lightgray}{5}\space\color{red}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{red}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{blue}{5}\space\color{red}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{red}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{blue}{5}\space\color{red}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{red}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
Here the blue sets are $\{1, 2\}, \{4, 5\}, \{7, 8\},$ while the red sets are $\{3, 4\}, \{6\}, \{8, 9, 10, 11\}.$ Hence Blue has a score of $6,$ while Red has a score of $7,$ so Red wins.

I've attempted to analyze the game using brute-force. Red doesn't seem to be able to win under optimal play by Blue. Blue sometimes has a winning strategy. For example, with $n$ odd and $m = 1,$ Blue may choose the middle number of the set as their first move, which forces Red to choose a number in one of the two sets that Blue separates, so Blue has a larger score. On the other hand, Blue can't always force a win. For example, with $n=11$ and $m\ge 2,$ Red can force a draw. Below I've coloured the first moves for Blue which guarantee a draw, i.e. drawing positions for Red (the numbers left gray represent winning positions for Red):
$$m=2:\space\space\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{lightgray}{2}\space\color{blue}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{lightgray}{5}\space\color{lightgray}{6}\space\color{lightgray}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{blue}{9}\space\color{lightgray}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$m=3:\space\space\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{blue}{3}\space\color{lightgray}{4}\space\color{blue}{5}\space\color{blue}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{lightgray}{8}\space\color{blue}{9}\space\color{blue}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$m=4:\space\space\color{lightgray}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{lightgray}{3}\space\color{blue}{4}\space\color{blue}{5}\space\color{blue}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{blue}{8}\space\color{lightgray}{9}\space\color{blue}{10}\space\color{lightgray}{11}$$
$$m=5:\space\space\color{blue}{1}\space\color{blue}{2}\space\color{blue}{3}\space\color{blue}{4}\space\color{blue}{5}\space\color{blue}{6}\space\color{blue}{7}\space\color{blue}{8}\space\color{blue}{9}\space\color{blue}{10}\space\color{blue}{11}$$
After observing the drawing positions for various odd $n,$ it seems that $\lfloor n / (2m) \rfloor + 1$ is optimal for blue for any $m.$ Also, for $n$ odd and $m\ge3,$ choosing the middle element seems to suffice for a draw. These are just observations for small $n,$ since the time needed to brute-force the winning positions grows rapidly with $n$.
Does Blue always have a winning/drawing strategy? If so, what is the strategy?
The game seems quite difficult to analyze so I'm not sure if we can even answer these questions.

If $n$ is even, red can force a draw by mirroring blue's moves.

first of all, as mentioned above for even n, red can force draw by mirroring blue.
now for the odd n: blue can always force a draw but also can win if choosing the middle is a good move! (for example for $n = 5, m = 2$ if blue chooses the middle at any point, they will lose with perfect play from red so it's a bad move).
So how can we force a win when a win is possible?
first, let's notice two important key ideas:
we don't want to get "boxed" meaning to have more than 1 colored number between two opponent-colored numbers, else it's a waste of a color, also we don't want to create too big spaces unless we "box" our opponent.
so the strategy is as follows:
first, we put on the $\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl]$ location, the idea is that it let us split the board evenly.
now if red puts below us we are on lead, because of course our cut is bigger so we will then put on $2\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl]$, and follows....
if red puts above our number, we will now choose the next number colored to be $$2\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl]$$ or $$3\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl]$$ if red is in the set of $\Bigr\{\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl], \ldots ,2\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl]\Bigl\}$, the idea is that if red picked there, we "box" them and therefore, it isn't worth it for them to pick it up again, we don't "box" them with higher values because then it will still be worth it for them to color another red.
for more general, if we are on split $a/m$, we will color the number:
$(a+r)\Bigr[\frac{n+1}{m+1}\Bigl]$ if it is smaller than $n$ ($r$ is the number of reds we encountered).
if we finish the first run with the remaining color, we will start the tight "boxing", meaning we will fill our large sections, this time trying to trap the reds there in small boxes.
why it's the best strategy given optimal play from red?
we make sure boxing us isn't worth it:
we split the board into almost equally sized spaces, so every space gives the same amount of numbers $A$. Now if red box us only once (minimum amount) they get to color reds in $m$ spaces IE they get $m*A$ score.
for every extra box red makes they must put two reds in the same space too, IE box themselves too, therefore they may make blue loss an entire box IE losses A score, but so those red because they occupy one less box now, therefore no change in red's strategy improves the deal for them.
now for the middle:
as in the even n case, red can mirror red actions and try achieving the same tactic, if the middle is a good location IE it does the best split of the space, then red can't mirror us and must put in an inferior location,
which makes the win assure. if the middle is a bad location as in the (5,2) case, then it's a draw.
I know it's a lot of hand waving, but still, I hope the idea behind is clear, I came up with the strategy thinking about the continuous game, where this strategy is obviously the best.

Also note: my math might be a bit wrong because of the edges (I for some reason assumed they behave like they are colored when they aren't, and noticed while writing this, so math is true for this case, but needs improvement for your presented game :).


For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
